# PnP Provisioning engine apply same configuration to all lists of a certain tpye

Tags: csom, pnp, remote-provisioning, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

As far as I can see from the PnP provisioning engine, each list instance needs to be specifically defined in the XML file. Is there a way that you can define one particular configuration to apply to all lists/libraries of a certain template type in a site? i.e. run it on a site and all document libraries get the same config.